# Custom Library component is not a known element, but app compiles and runs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

> **The Problem**

My html files warn that my custom components/pipes 'are not a known element'. However building and running the application **works as intended**, and the custom components/pipes are functional. The dichotomy of the components working but showing as errors is annoying and can be difficult to work with. I know this is a small thing, but I really want to not see errors in my html files when there are no errors.

> **Summary**

I have two distinct angular projects; an angular library which I consume with my angular application. The library exports several custom components, pipes and services which the application uses. I do not have this library published via npm, instead I use npm-link to give the application access to the library. This seems to work as any service/component defined in my applications components work and doesn't complain. Though the moment I put anything in my template file from my library, that selector is underlined and a warning appears.

> **The files**

```
/*Library Module*/
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ThemeToggleComponent,
    // Other custom components/pipes
  ],
  exports: [
    ThemeToggleComponent,
    // Other components needed in templates files
  ]
})
export class MyCommonModule {}
```

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of my-common library
 */

export * from './lib/my-common.module';
/*
 * Many other components, services, pipes, etc etc
 */
export * from './lib/theme-toggle/theme-toggle.component';
```

```
/* Consuming Application module */
import { MyCommonModule } from 'my-common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyCommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
  ],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

```
/* Template of MyComponent, my.component.html */
<div>
  <my-theme-toggle (darkThemeSelected)="toggleTheme($event)"></my-theme-toggle>
</div>
```

The file above will have all lines which reference my custom components underlined in red with the error message **'my-theme-toggle' is not a known element: ...if it is, verify it is apart of the module**.

> **Attempts to fix**

I've tried a things, but to no avail

- Not using NPM link and just copying the library created by ng-packagr into the node modules of my application
- Rebuilding and relinking/restarting everything
- Searching for other S.O questions: most questions are about build failures because the import/export was actually incorrect.

> **My hunches**

I think this is an issue with the *paths* compiler option in tsconfig.json in the consuming application. Throughout all of my research this is the one thing that pops up more than anything else. I currently do not have a path set, because everything is working. My common library looks and acts like any other node_module library, other than this issue.

My other thought is that because everything works and runs, then the issue may be with vs-code not understanding the import, or something of that nature. Though I think this is unlikely.

> **The background**

Both angular projects are on version 9, rc7. I use ng-packagr to build my library. I use visual studio code, and at the time of writing I am on the latest release.

**EDIT**
This problem went away upon upgrading to angular 11, I think several of the other issues might solve it, but this feels like the best option.

Comment: maybe vs code doesn't understand the symlink,  what if you `npm install <path-to-library>` instead?

Comment: @JasonWhite that my thought as well, but doing your suggestion resulted in the same outcome of just copying my library directly into node_modules. It all works, but still gives me errors in my .html files.

Comment: Maybe open an issue on their Github page?

Comment: Looks like the language server [does not support ivy](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/645). They say to fix this run a build with the `--prod` flag on the library, then run `Restart Angular Language Service`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think it is exactly the issue I have, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: My library is built with the prod flag, and I have the right metadata file generated in it to confirm it. Unfortunately the Language Service is not recognizing my components...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Its An Import Problem, 99.99% of the time!

I've seen this question posted in slightly different ways on different sites, within and out of Stack Overflow. I can tell you its probably not an issue with Angular Language Service.

#### There are three reasons this can happen

1. how you've exported the missing Component from the library, e.g. check if you:

   - Added `export * from <your-component>` to your `public-api.ts` file
   - Added your Component to the `exports` of the Library Module that exports it
2. how you're importing the Library Component, e.g. check if you:

   - linked the library? `cd /path/to/<your-library> && npm link`
   - linked the application?: `cd /path/to/app && npm link <your-library>`
   - added the library NgModule(s) `YourLibraryModule` to `imports:[]` of your Applications main NgModule
3. You maybe forgot to declare the parent component in your App NgModule!!

   - This one is huge and not mentioned often. In Angular 10, 11, you can forget to add the Application Component to `declarations` that references the missing library Component, and the language service / compiler will complain that the Library Component is missing, but not mention the App Component is incorrectly exported!

### Why Angular Language Service Restart?

Sometimes the error may change once you restart the language service (e.g. restart VSCode). For scenario 3 I mentioned above, the error becomes:

```sh
Error: Cannot determine the module for class YourAppComponent in YourApp/src/app/components/your-app-component/your-app-component.component.ts! Add YourAppComponent to the NgModule to fix it
```

And voila!! You see the real problem and fixing it is easy!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. "Added your Component to the exports of the Library Module that exports it" was what was killing me.

Comment: 3 was the one for me.

Comment: Thank you a lot, in my case it was the third point. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 11):

To fix the issue, you currently have to build with the production flag `--prod`, because, in its current state, the [Angular Language Server doesn't work with Ivy](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/645) builds. By default the angular prod build builds without Ivy. Thus when it is built, it creates a `lib.metadata.json` file. This is the file that the language server uses to make the plugin work.

1. **In your library**, create a build `ng build <lib> --prod`

   - add the `--watch` flag to watch for changes
2. **In your library**, create a link `cd dist` then `npm link`

   - I created a `package.json` in the `dist` folder and created the link there since my lib has multiple modules in it. This will allow you to do

     - `import { ModuleAComponent } from '<lib>/moduleA'`
     - `import { ModuleADirective } from '<lib>/moduleA'`
   - **Note:** The folder you link must have a `package.json` otherwise it will use the root of the project since that is the closest `package.json`
   - If you do the same the paths below are in the correct format otherwise they may not be and you can try: `"lib": ["./node_modules/lib", "./node_modules/lib/*"]`
3. **In your application**, link to the package `npm link <lib>`
4. **In your application**, create a `path` in your `tsconfig.base.json` (The path might be different depending on how you created your link)
5. **In your application**, Restart the Angular Language Server

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": [
        "./node_modules/lib/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I never had that described error until recently.

After uninstalling the Angular Language Service extension (which I had installed recently) the error went away.

Comment: Verified this does work, but I'm uneasy about accepting this as an answer. The Angular Language Service is really useful for catching common errors, autocompleting variable names and many other things.

This may hint at a potential source of the issue though.

Comment: Why not update this answer to explain how to "restart" the Angular Language Service :)

Answer (score 2):

I switched my projects from Angular 8 to 9 and had the same problem in VS Code. My solution that worked for me:

- Build the library with configuration production: `ng build my-lib --prod` => This will force the compiler to use the older View Engine instead of Ivy ([Angular docs libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#publishing-your-library))
- Go to the folder "./dist/my-lib/" and use `npm pack` instead of `npm link` => this will create a tgz-file, which you can install in your consuming app.
- Install the library in your consuming app: `npm install "D:/mypath/dist/my-lib/my-lib-2.1.0.tgz"`

This solves in my environment VS Code's issue with Angular 9.

Comment: this was an interesting idea, but unfortunately did not work for me. I followed the steps and verified that the soft link indicators were not showing up, indicating I was using the tarball itself. I wish this would have worked though.

Comment: What happens if you try the steps with two new apps? An app with a test library and a consuming app. In my setting, I sometimes have the problem you described, but when I restart VS Code, the links to the library in the html templates are working again. Magic... Sounds like a caching problem in VS Code.

Comment: I have not given this a shot yet, but I will try to reproduce my issue with a minimum viable product and update the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following approach.
https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/645#issuecomment-648283157
In a nutshell:

- Build you lib with the --prod flag.
- Then go to `dist/YourLibName` and run `npm link`
- Go to the project that will be using the lib and run `npm link YourLibName` name from the lib package.json
- In the project tsconfig.json add paths property to the compilerOptions.

```
    {  
      "compilerOptions": {
       .
       .
       .
        "paths": {
          "YourLibName from lib package.json": ["node_modules/YourLibPath"]
        },
```

Then you will be able to use it just like any library e.g. material.

Comment: Thanks -- all it needed was building with the --prod flag for it to work on my side with latest angualr version (11.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same issue while developing a custom library. I was using the link between the app and the lib.

I fixed adding preserveSymlinks under compilerOptions inside the tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    ...
```

Check [here](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/657#issuecomment-595610290) for more details.

Comment: this worked for me in monorepo. Simple solution, just add it inside parent tsconfig or tsconfig.base depending on your nx version

Answer (score -3):

I have exactly the same problem. Here is a fix,

Adding

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

and

```
schemas: [
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
],
```

to your module

---

A complete `app.module.ts` for your reference

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgNiceSelectModule } from 'ng-nice-select';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgNiceSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This will remove errors from displaying, however it also allows other errors to slip through. For instance, <some-bad-thing></some-bad-thing> will not show as an error.

This technically works, but possibly breaks too much other functionality to be accepted as an answer.