# How do I create an angular component as part of a library and use it in my application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, node-modules, angular-components

So I have the following situation

1. I have created an angular library `ng generate library my-lib`
2. I have added a simple component using `Ng generate component .lib/test` which creates a standalone component
   like so

> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'lib-test',
>   standalone: true,
>   imports: [],
>   templateUrl: './test.component.html',
>   styleUrl: './test.component.css'
> })
> export class TestComponent {
>
> }
> ```

3. I then pack up my application by running `ng build` then `cd ../../dist/my-lib && npm pack`
4. I go to my main application and run `npm install {pointTofolder}/dist/my-lib/my-lib-0.0.1.tgz`
5. I go to use  in my application and I get the following error

> 'lib-test' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'lib-test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'lib-test' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

What am I missing / doing wrong? It's the most simple example of using a component in a library

Comment: 1) If your library and application are inside the same workspace then you can first build your library, next write code in your application, then build your application. 2) However instead I would suggest to take a look at a monorepo tool like [NX](https://nx.dev) where you can point directly to your library source code, without having to compile your library on each change. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player) an example of an application with some libs inside an NX workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used these two links

1. [Standalone component NG8001: 'component' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470784/standalone-component-ng8001-component-is-not-a-known-element)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65740167/2987066

And this lead me to the following:

1. Make sure the route is importing the module the Import's and Export's of that module

   ```
    const routes: Routes = [
   {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./routes/my/my.module').then(m => m.MyModule)
      },
    ]
   }];
   ```

Then make sure that the component you want to load is in both the imports and the exports of the module you just loaded above (for standalone componets)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    TestComponent
  ],
    declarations: [

  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    TestComponent
  ]
})
```

If your component is not a **Standalone component**, you can do the same thing but import it through a module

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    CommonUiModule
  ],
    declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    CommonUiModule
  ]
```

And in this case `CommonUiModule` looks like the following

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    TestComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    TestComponent
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be caused by following reasons:

- You didn't add export to `public-api.ts` in your library, like

```js
export * from './lib/page-layout/page-layout.component';
```

- You didn't add `TestComponent` to `imports` in `@Component` directive in your main Angular application, like

```js
@Component({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    TestComponent,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

- You built and added your library to dependencies incorrectly. To build library, I use

```bash
ng build
```

or

```bash
ng build --configuration production
```

and to add library to dependencies, I have entry in `package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular-components": "file:../utility/feature/angular_components/dist/angular-components",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

- You may also need to add `"preserveSymlinks": true,` to your `angular.json`, like

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
...
```